# How can I correctly instantiate an octree in UE4?

Tags: c++, unreal, octree

I tried to create a simple Octree like this:
(I looked at the [FMeshTriOctree source code](https://github.com/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/blob/97c8d3ef55e869e17ef149903eae2a33101381c9/Engine/Source/Editor/MeshPaint/Private/MeshPaintStaticMeshAdapter.h#L42) since no question in [answers.unrealengine.com](https://answers.unrealengine.com) helped me)

```
// My FVertex class is slightly more complexe, but let's say it's something like this:
class FVertex : public FVector
{
      int32 ID;
}

struct FVertexOctreeSemantics
{
        enum { MaxElementsPerLeaf = 16 };
        enum { MinInclusiveElementsPerNode = 7 };
        enum { MaxNodeDepth = 12 };

        typedef TInlineAllocator<MaxElementsPerLeaf> ElementAllocator;

        FORCEINLINE static FBoxCenterAndExtent GetBoundingBox(const PBS::FVertex* Vertex)
        {
            return FBoxCenterAndExtent(Vertex->GetBoundingBox());
        }

        FORCEINLINE static bool AreElementsEqual(const PBS::FVertex* A, const PBS::FVertex* B)
        {
            return A==B;
        }

        /** Ignored for this implementation */
        FORCEINLINE static void SetElementId(const PBS::FVertex* Element, FOctreeElementId Id){}
};

typedef TOctree<PBS::FVertex*, FVertexOctreeSemantics> FVOctree;
```

But when I instanciate my octree it returns:

```
Fatal error: [File:D:\BuildFarm\buildmachine_++depot+UE4-Releases+4.9\Engine\Source\Runtime\Core\Private\Misc\CoreMisc.cpp] [Line: 975] 
The TOctree() constructor is for internal usage only for hot-reload purposes. Please do NOT use it.
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is telling you that the default constructor of `TOctree` isn't something you're supposed to use directly. Instead, use a different constructor. You probably want to use the one that takes a center point and an extent:

```
TOctree(const FVector& InOrigin,float InExtent)
```

If you notice, the example source code you linked to stores a pointer to the octree type:

```
TUniquePtr<FMeshTriOctree> MeshTriOctree;
```

which it then instantiates as

```
MeshTriOctree = MakeUnique<FMeshTriOctree>(
  Bounds.GetCenter(),
  Bounds.GetExtent().GetMax()
);
```

The default constructor is only available when building with hot-reload constructors enabled; if you were to disable that option you'll get a regular old compile error, so you shouldn't rely on that constructors existence.

Comment: I posted [this question on answers.unrealengine.com](https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/383590/how-to-use-octree-again.html) as well, do you want to answer it, or should I do it?